# Geometry problems: Area problem...[Homework]

Tags: geometry

1) $\triangle ABC: D \in AB; E\in BC$ such that $BD=3AD$, $BE = 4EC$. F is the intersection of AE and CD. Prove that FD = FC
(I think we should prove $S_{ACE} = S_{ADE} = \frac{S_{ABE}}{4}$)

2)$\triangle ABC: \widehat{A}=90^o, AM \perp BD$ (AM and BD are medians) . $AB = \sqrt{2}$. Find $S_{ABC}$

3)$\triangle ABC: \widehat{A}=30^0;  \widehat{B}=50^0$ Prove $ab = c^2 - b^2$ ($\ AB=c; AC=b; BC=a$)

I think we 'll prove $$\frac{c+b}{c} = \frac{c}{b} => b(b+c)=c^2$$

Please help me, I have more than 10 exercises and have to finish it in one day :pokerface:. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1) Make an affine transformation (this does not affect any of the length ratios) such that $AE$ becomes the bisector of $\hat A$. Since the bisector splits the opposite side in the proportion of the adjacent sides, this will be the case iff $AB=4AC$, i.e. $AD=AC$. Again, because the bisector splits the opposite side in the proportion of the adjacent sides, we conclude $DF=FC$.

Comment: I proved that now It is easy to prove $$S_{ACE} = S_{ADE} = \frac{S_{ABE}}{4}$$, after that, everything is easy too
But I haven't done Ex. 2 and 3 yet

Comment: I finished all of the things now :D, Can't believe it was so easy

Comment: Ah, great to hear. Indeed, going via the areas is equivalent to though probably less obscure than making the affine transformation argument (after all the theorem about bisectors I used is readily proved via area comparison).